# bluetooth mouse and keyboard on surface pro interfere

Tags: wireless-networking, keyboard, mouse, bluetooth

Over the last few years, I've used a number (I've got 4 sets!) of: https://www.kogan.com/au/buy/wireless-bluetooth-keyboard-and-mouse-combo/
to connect full size keyboards and mice to my tablets and notebooks without keypads.  I do a lot of navigation and having my hands learn only one set of muscle memories is VERY useful.

Anyway,  my wife bought a Surface Pro-3 and we connected the two up, but she normally doesn't use the keyboard only the mouse.

Today we discovered that when the keyboard is active, the mouse is disabled.  This is the only machine on which this happens.  I've also noticed that when I try to pair more than one keyboard, unlike the other machines which recognise each keyboard separately, it seems to think they are all the same keyboard.

Can anyone explain why the combo doesn't work on the Surface Pro?